# StreamSocket DataReader ReadToEnd extension method

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-runtime, .net-4.5

I would like to implement an extension method called ReadToEnd on the `Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader` class. This should basically read all available data on the stream like System.IO.StreamReader.

Trying to make porting of my non-compliant WinRT code as easy as possible.

I'm not sure about how to achieve this, or if it is even possible.

Comment: `System.IO.Stream` doesn't have a `ReadToEnd()` method. Are you talking about `System.IO.TextReader.ReadToEnd()`? Also why is there `StreamSocket` in your question title? How is this related to your question?

Comment: Hi Darin. You are correct. Ammended question accordingly. With regards to StreamSocket, i referenced it as you usually use the DataReader in conjunction with that. Hopefully, developers that have worked alot with StreamSocket will have a solution, as they may have done something similar.

Comment: When you are dealing with network streams having a `ReadToEnd` operation doesn't make any sense. The reading from the socket will block if there's no more data available and your code will hang. Usually when you are dealing with Sockets you are working with some protocol over TCP such as HTTP for example. Each protocol should have a way for specifying how much data is available for reading otherwise the client wouldn't know how much to read and will hang if he attempts to read more. For example in the HTTP protocol the server indicates this through the `Content-Length` response header.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov In HTTP/1.0 it is quite common to not supply a `Content-Length` and the client relies on the server closing the connection to indicate all data has been transferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to write something that gives me what I required.

```
internal static string ReadLine(this DataReader stream, ref int maxLength, Encoding encoding, char? termChar)
{
    var maxLengthSpecified = maxLength > 0;
    int i;
    byte b = 0, b0;
    var read = false;
    using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
    {
        while (true)
        {
            b0 = b;
            i = stream.ReadByte();
            if (i == -1) break;
            else read = true;

            b = (byte)i;
            if (maxLengthSpecified) maxLength--;

            if (maxLengthSpecified && mem.Length == 1 && b == termChar && b0 == termChar)
            {
                maxLength++;
                continue;
            }

            if (b == 10 || b == 13)
            {
                if (mem.Length == 0 && b == 10)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else break;
            }

            mem.WriteByte(b);
            if (maxLengthSpecified && maxLength == 0)
                break;
        }

        if (mem.Length == 0 && !read) return null;
        return encoding.GetString(mem.ToArray(), 0, (int)mem.Length);
    }
}
```